# Convert between double and float precision in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

How do I convert a number from double-precision to single-precision and back?

For example, I have this in Java/C/C#:

```
double x = 0.00001;
float f = (float)x; // should be 0.000009999999747378752 not 0.0000100000000000000008180305391403
int n = Math.floor(1001 * f / x); // should be 1000 not 1001.
```

(don't ask. this is a simplified version of what some hairy C code looks like and I need to port it 1:1)

Another example:

```
double y = Math.floor((double)(float)5.999999876); // should be 6.0
```

---

What I already tried:

```
var f:float = x; // syntax error
var f = x as float; // syntax error
var f = parseFloat(x); // returns full double-precision (0.0000100000000000000008180305391403)
var f = toFixed(x, ...); // Can't use this as float is not defined by number of decimal places but number of binary places.
```

---

I'm using Rhino (as part of Java 7), and it should also be compatible with Nashorn (as part of Java 8). I have access to the entire public Java API, if this helps.

---

[Edit] I did some more experiments and it seems like the problem is not in the float conversion but in the float operations. I really need the FPU in my processor to perform a single-precision `fmul` here. `1001 * f` doesn't work if `f` contains the float precision version of `0.00001` in a double-precision number. The only way I get an exact result is if I perform a 32-bit multiplication on `1001f * 0.00001f` and *then* obtain the result.

Comment: Javascript only has [one `Number` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: I know it has one `Number` type, but you still have functions like `floor()` that *effectively* makes it an int (but not really).

Comment: You really need to clarify if this is about Java or Javascript... you seem to be using the two terms interchangeably, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: I think Math.floor() is a misleading example because you'd expect it to convert precision (`4.2 -> 4`) when in fact it doesn't (`4.20000 -> 4.00001`).

Comment: @Sphygmomanometer on my system it doesn't. I get a neat integer, and floating point numbers are always completely accurate with integers that fall within their mantissa range (53 bits).

Comment: I know what you mean and before it gets any more confusing: What you are looking for is not part of the language. But you can achieve that with libraries like the one I mentioned in my answer. It allows you to do precision conversions.

Answer (score 5):

This will convert a number to float in javascript:

```
new Float32Array([15.603179021718429])[0]
```

The answer is:

```
15.603178977966309
```

Oops, even easier, use `Math.fround()`.  New in ES6.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript itself doesn't provide any such feature. I recommend you use [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js) if you absolutely need precision conversions.

Answer (score 0):

All numerical values in JavaScript are `Number`s
They are all 64-bit floating point numbers.

[Read more here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html)

Comment: That's not an answer. `0.000009999999747378752` can also be represented in 64-bit double, so the question is how do I get that number when I have `0.0000100000000000000008180305391403`?